# PHP Email Script Issue

Tags: php, email

Hi there I have edited some code I have found on-line and everything works besides the validation. It always seems to send an email even when all fields are blank on the contact form that I've created. It is definitely an easy fix but I'm new to this so any help means a great deal to me!!

Thanks.

Heres the code Im using for the php script:

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
<?php
// Contact subject
$subject ="$Email Enquiry"; 
// Details
$message=("$cComment") ; 

// Mail of sender
$mail_from="$cEmail"; 
// From 
$header="from: $cName <$mail_from>"; 

// Enter your email address
$to ='info@blahblahblah.net'; 

$send_contact=mail($to,$subject,$message, $header);

// Check, if message sent to your email 
// display message "We've recived your information"
if($mail_from != "Email"){
header('Location:thanksemail.php');
}
else {
header('Location:emailfail.php');
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't got any checking code. The code that sends the mail is $send_contact=mail($to,$subject,$message, $header);
The checking must be before this code

Try this

```
if($subject!="" && $cComment!="" && $cEmail!="" && $cName!="" && $mail_from!=""){
$send_contact=mail($to,$subject,$message, $header);

if($mail_from != "Email"){
header('Location:thanksemail.php');
}
else {
header('Location:emailfail.php');
}


}else{
header('Location:emailfail.php');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to check if the variables are empty before sending the email. You can do this like so:

```
if(!empty($variable) and
   !empty($variable2)) {
    // send the email out here
}
```

I am using the [`empty()`](http://php.net/empty) function here to detect if the values are empty or not. The following values are considered to be empty values:

> ```
> "" (an empty string)
> 0 (0 as an integer)
> 0.0 (0 as a float)
> "0" (0 as a string)
> NULL
> FALSE
> array() (an empty array)
> var $var; (a variable declared, but without a value in a class)
> ```

I would also avoid using the standard PHP mail function and instead use a library such as [PHPMailer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/) or [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) to send out your emails instead. They give you more flexibility and both have a much nicer API to work with.

Comment: Need to make sure you don't make the mail($to,$subject,$message, $header) call if $to etc are equal to ""/null

Comment: @BeRecursive I am not sure what you are getting at. Please see the manual page for the `empty()` function http://php.net/empty for more information about what is counted as an empty value.

Comment: Sorry that was pretty unclear - I simply wanted to highlight that the mail() function call was actually sending the email and thats what needed to be inside your well explained if-statements

Answer (score 0):

Just as a side note, you can save yourself a line or two of code by verifying if the e-mail was sent like:

```
if(mail($to,$subject,$message, $header)){
     header('Location:thanksemail.php');
}else {
     header('Location:emailfail.php');
}
```

If it comes back true, it was sent.  If false, it was not sent.

Answer (score 0):

You have put the **mail()** function outside your **if() statement**.

Just move it (and complete your if with the other fields):

```
<?php
if(!empty($mail_from) && !empty($Email)) {
  mail($to, $subject, $message, $header);
  header('Location:thanksemail.php');
} else {
 header('Location:emailfail.php');
}
```